# SQL insert of '' is neither null or empty in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a function that essentially copies records and inserts them with new IDs. The code works and everything copies fine.

The SQL that occurs is essentially:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, field, select) VALUES ('newID','stuff','')
```

Notice the last value is blank,empty,null, whatever. Sometimes it has something in it, sometimes it doesn't.

I have a check against that value in an access form and it uses isNull or isEmpty and both come up false, with only records that are inserted in this manner.

So what is being inserted, if nothing is being inserted? it's neither null nor empty and there is nothing in there, so I'm completely baffled. If I enter something and wipe it out, it'll be fine.

Comment: What is the definition of table `myTable`?

Comment: Note, too, that for ANSI-compliant SQL, a zero-length string is not the same as `NULL`.  Access (and SQL Server) are ANSI compliant in this way, though some major databases are not (Oracle, most notably).  Also, some people would take a "blank string" to mean something different from both: a string containing only one or more space characters.

Comment: the field in question is a varchar. I'm unsure about the ANSI ness, but this may be in the right direction. I'm thinking it could be a bug in Access. There is more to the method of the function before it, but I print out all the sql statements that occur and they don't show any anomalies

Comment: did you try testing for the empty string, '' (2 single quotes)?

Comment: select is not a good idea for a field name by the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

The IsEmpty() Function is generally only of use to check to see if a variable of type variant has not been initialised.

A database field can be said to be empty which is not the same as if it was Null.

For example if you have a field called Gender which was not a required field on a new record the value could be Null, then if a user typed in Female obviously it would a contain value.  If they were then to delete the word Female then the field would now be empty (Not Null).

The most useful function to use when dealing with Nulls in Microsoft Access is the following:

```
Nz()
```

This function has two arguments, the first one being the variable you wish to check and the second one being the value you wish to return if the variable is Null.  For example the following will return an empty string:

```
Dim variantName As Variant
variantName = Null
Debug.Print Nz(variantName,"")
```

Also please note if you try to join a variable that contains Null with a String using the plus character (+) then this will result in Null which is probably where you're having problems.

A try typing the following into the immediate window results are also shown here:

```
? len(null)
Null

? len(null + "abc")
Null

? len(null & "abc")
3
```

Comment: So, basically, if a record from that table is loaded into a form, then `isEmpty()` should return `false` for each field bound to any column of the record.  If you want to check for a zero-length string then compare to a zero-length string or check the string length.  You might wish to trim whitespace from the ends of the string first.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the field, just checking if it's null. originally it was using IsNull, and that worked, but not with records inserted in this manner. It will come up as false, so I thought maybe maybe it was empty, and tried IsEmpty and still producing false. So Access thinks something is there... until I manually go in and enter something and then delete it, then it becomes null.

Comment: Again, a zero-length string is not the same thing as `NULL` (except within the the warped confines of Oracle-land, and perhaps a few other odd places).  `isNull("")` will return `false` in Access.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes I agree, isnull is returning false, but so is isEmpty, that's returning false to. I just did a len(field) = 0, that returns false, then I just output the len(field) and that outputs nothing. can the length of the field be null? wouldn't that default as the field being null? otherwise it'd be 0 and that would mean the field is empty. man this is mind boggling. I'm thinking it is an access bug.

Comment: If you want to confirm that a control has text in it and you don't care whether it's Null or empty the following code would return true : If Len(controlName & "")>0 Then

Comment: alright I found a stupid work around. I did an iff for len(field)=0 or isnull(len(field)) and that worked. I don't get why isnull(field) or isempty(field) doesn't work. once again I think it's an access bug. FREKAIN ACCESS

Comment: @thomas No, it's not a bug. Access has behaved this way for a long time. Part of your confusion is caused by the Access UI being "helpful". If you leave a bound Text Box empty or delete the text that was in it - NB, Mark3308 - then the control's `.Value` will be `Null` and Access will set the bound field to `Null` if it can. That's why "If [you] enter something and wipe it out, it'll be fine [i.e., `Null`]." If you want to save an empty string via a Text Box you have to type `""` into it. That produces the same result as `''` in an SQL statement.

Answer (score -2):

could be a \r or \n or any other non printable character,
you may want to select such a row and cast it as varbinary to see the content

Comment: A zero-length string is being specified, or so the question explicitly says.  There is no reason to think that the value actually inserted instead contains a control character.

Comment: It says in the question the string is blank, null, empty, whatever. Blank could mean it contains whitespaces (and is not zero-length) and a zero-length string is not the same as null, not to mention what whatever could all mean. So I think my hint is still valid.